# Best Practice to update or modify an Array in Array with redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I would like to know the best practice and if my way was correct to update or modify an array in array.

Currently, I have this state :

**State**

```
props1 : "props1",
props2 : "props2",
props3 : "props3",
buckets : [{
    bucketProps1 : "bucketProps1",
    bucketProps2 : "bucketProps2",
    bucketProps3 : "bucketProps3",
    blocks : [{
        blockProps1 : "blockProps1",
        blockProps2 : "blockProps2",
        blockProps3 : "blockProps3",
        messages : [{
            messageProps1 : "messageProps1",
            messageProps2 : "messageProps2",
            messageProps3 : "messageProps3",
            replies : [{ 
                repliesProps1 : "repliesProps1",
                repliesProps2 : "repliesProps2",
                repliesProps3 : "repliesProps3",
            },
            {...
            }],
        },
        {...
        }],
    },
    {...
    }],
},
{...
}]
```

I would like to add a reply in the replies array :

**reducer-sequences.js**

```
case SEQUENCES.ADD_REPLY :

let newReplies = action.payload;

return {
...state,
buckets: state.buckets.map((bucket, i) => i === 0 ? {
        ...bucket,
        blocks: bucket.blocks.map((block, i) => i === 0 ? {
            ...block,
            messages: block.messages.map((message, i) => i === 0 ? {
                ...message,
                replies: [...state.buckets[0].blocks[0].messages[0].replies, newReplies]
            } : message)
        } : block)
    } : bucket)
};
```

Is there a best practice than this one to edit an array in an array ?

Do you have a suggestion to refactoring this code ?

Thank you !

Comment: I once used lodash's merge function in a project to solve this. If you need a new array, you just clone it after merging. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the option of normalising your state to a structure that's easier to deal with I'd suggest using [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) for this.

```
import produce from "immer";

...

case SEQUENCES.ADD_REPLY:
  let newReplies = action.payload;
  return produce(state, draft => {
    draft.buckets[0].blocks[0].messages[0].replies.push(newReplies);
  });
};
```